# Stop reusing the ASP.NET_sessionId

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got a strange problem with a (not live yet) website and I don't know what the cause of the problem is.

Take this scenario:

1. I log in on the site with userA.
2. I open F12 and copy the cookie values of ASP.NET_SessionId and .AspNet.ApplicationCookie
3. UserA logs off. This codeblock is executed:

   ```
   HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

   Session.Clear();
   Session.Abandon();
   Session.RemoveAll();

   Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1d);
   Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = "";
   Response.Cookies.Add(Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"]);

   return Redirect($"{AppSettings.PublicLandingPage}/loggedout");
   ```
4. UserB logs in.
5. I paste the values from step2 into new userB cookie values
6. I navigate to an other page of the site
7. I'm now logged in as userA

The questions I have now:

- Is this expected behavior? If not, what would be the cause of this problem?
- Is there any way to kill the session on the serverside? In my web.config the session-timeout is set to 10minutes and the site succesfully logs off, but when logging back in with any user and copying the 'old' cookie data, the session still seems to be alive, even after 48hrs.
- I haven't tried it yet, but if I would execute these steps on another IP-adres, can I expect the same behavior? Is there a way to block this?

Regards!

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing authentication with session - those are separate concepts - you can have active session without being authenticated or be authenticated without active session.

As for why you're authenticated - that is by design. Authentication cookie contains so called ticket - usually it consist of encrypted UserID, Timestamp (cookie is useless after timestamp expires) and some other info. There is nothing stored in server memory - so you can have load balancer / web server farm and users will be authenticated seamlessly. Cookie (based on encrypted timestamp) can use either absolute expiration or sliding expiration. If sliding expiration is used server (once browser send request and half of the sliding expiration period has passed) replaces auth cookie with new one, with fresh timestamp.

If you're concerned about cookie theft - check first you use https and http-only cookies :) If you need to tighten the security even more be aware that IP-based cookie protection can lead to usability issues - like when you're moving from one wifi to another with notebook/phone - you're signed out and there are other things you can use as browser fingerprint - like user agent string, etc.

Comment: Hi Ondrej! You are absolutely right. The session has nothing to do with the authentication part. We currently have https http-only cookies.
Not using the IP-based cookie is a good remark.
The only thing I still can't get my head around is the ticket with encrypted UserID. It seems logical that as long as the user is logged in, the ticket is valid for the period of the timestamp, but when the user logs out, I hoped that this ticket would be invalidated so you can't use that ticket any more? But as you mentioned, that would be impossible as there is nothing stored server side...

Comment: Hi @OndrejSvejdar! I was wondering if there's any way to handle the scenario where auth and session cookies are stolen!
I understand it's unlikely and it sort of defeats the purpose. But none the less...